# Problems in MPICH 3.1.3 installation in OSX 10.10 with ifort compiler and Xcode 6.1

Tags: osx-yosemite, intel-fortran, icc, mpich

I am trying to build mpich 3.1.3. in a Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite with Xcode 6.1 and intel compilers icc and ifort version 15.0.0 20140716. I get an error when I am building the installation. The error is the following:

```
 GEN      lib/libpmpi.la
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-force_load,src/mpl/.libs/libmpl.a'
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-force_load,/Users/alejandrodelacallenegro/Downloads/mpich-3.1.3/src/openpa/src/.libs/libopa.a'
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-force_load,src/mpi/romio/.libs/libpromio.a'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: object: lib/.libs/libpmpi.a(initthread.o) malformed object (section contents at offset 0 with a size of 1056, overlaps Mach-O headers at offset 0 with a size of 768)
```

I do not understand where the error come from, from the compiler or from libtool. I have also attached the outputs of the configuration and the build steps.

Comment: Can you add your configure line? Most likely, you'll need provide more information (configure logs, make logs, etc.). You should probably send an email to discuss@mpich.org to get more assistance directly from the MPICH team.

Comment: Thank you Wesley. Here is my configure line:  'CC=icc' 'CXX=icpc' 'F77=ifort' 'FC=ifort' '--prefix=/opt/mpich/3.1.3/' I am going to send an email to the MPICH discussion group.

Comment: That will probably be necessary. You should include your `config.log` in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause of the problem. libtool was somehow corrupted, so I install it again, and then I don't get this error anymore. I have install Xcode again, but I suppose that installing it from macports, homebrew or from source solves the problem as well.

Alex